# Part identification - Red 2x2 tile with fire print

Tags: part-identification

Can anyone help me identify this part. I know it was probably from the 90’s. Thank you[image]

Answer (score 5):

This is part # [3068bp57 : Tile 2 x 2 with Groove with Classic Fire Logo Small Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3068bp57#T=C&C=5)

It was released from 1986 until 1994 and appears in [5 sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3068bp57&in=S)